# How to print in applet outside paint() method

Tags: java, graphics, applet, awt, paint

I've been trying to print using the **drawString()** function of **Graphics** class in a method other than **paint()**. I've tried this program which was the solution to an earlier doubt, but this code is not working. Please find me the flaws. Thanks.
Here's it below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class PaintIssue extends Applet {

    Graphics gg; //global Graphics object

    @Override
    public void init() {}

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Output of paint method",20,20);
        myMethod(); //calling myMethod
    }

    public static void myMethod() {
        gg.drawString("Output of myMethod",20,40);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Comment: Well I'm new to applets and AWT is the only thing I've learnt so far regarding graphics manipulation. I've been doing them for a year now.

Comment: You'll get better help & better answers, on Swing and desktop apps.

Comment: I'm sure I will. I hope to start with Swing soon. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWT doesn't have a concept of a "global graphics object". You have to pass down the Graphics object that your paint method receives.

```
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Output of paint method",20,20);
        myMethod(g); //calling myMethod
    }

    public static void myMethod(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Output of myMethod",20,40);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem once again. :)